# DialogFragment won't open after 30 times - android

Tags: fragment, dialogfragment

I came across a problem in dialog fragment. After opening dialogfragment 30 times, the next one blur the screen but no content. Is there a solution??

here is parent fragment:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new B3Fragment();
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
```

Here is my onCreateDialog:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_b3, new LinearLayout(getActivity()), false);

    // Build dialog
    Dialog builder = new Dialog(getActivity());
    builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    builder.setContentView(view);
    return builder;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating the dialog, You must create dialog before return it.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_b3, new LinearLayout(getActivity()), false);

    // Build dialog
    Dialog.Builder builder = new Dialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    builder.setContentView(view);
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: thanks, i mentioned that we should use Alertdialog instead of Dialog.note that Dilaog doesn't have builder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `Dialog.Builder.create()` instead of `new Dialog()`.